# Can I create a channel at bot on startup?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to create a channel with Discord.js using the `message.guild.createChannel` function. But, I need to send a message on the server for the bot to do that. How can I do it at the bot startup ? I think I need to implement my code into the `bot.on('ready', () => {` function, but I don't know how. Thanks !

This is my code:

```
var firstLog = false;

bot.on('message', msg => {
  if (!firstLog) {
    msg.guild.createChannel('raidprotect-logs', "text")
  } firstLog = true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use somethink like this if you want use it on message

```
var firstLog = false;

bot.on('message', msg => {
  if (!firstLog) msg.guild.createChannel('new-general', { type: 'text' })
firstLog = true;
});
```

If you want you use it when bot start , you need get guild fist.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    let myGuild = bot.guilds.get('GUILDID HERE')
   myGuild.createChannel('new-general', { type: 'text' })
        .then(console.log(“done”))
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Here's how you do it

```
    bot.on('ready', () => {
     guild.createChannel('new-general', { type: 'text' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
    });
```

As they suggested [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel)

You can find more help on [Discord.js Official discord](https://discordapp.com/invite/bRCvFy9) server

Comment: I get the error `ReferenceError: guild is not defined`, and I don't know how to patch it.